# Tensorflow: tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError

Tags: tensorflow

I came across an error while invoking the Tensorflow model:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder_42' with dtype float and shape [?]
```

Code:

````
"""
This file is the main entry point for the service. It's responsible for loading
the model and implementing the "invoke" function.
"""

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import json
import logging

global tf_graph

import time

# load the vocabulary
with open('/opt/ml/model/vocab_dict.json', 'r') as f:
    vocab_dict = json.load(f)

def encode(text_tensor, label):
  encoded_text = [vocab_dict[t] for t in text_tensor.numpy().decode('UTF-8').split(' ')]
  return encoded_text, label

def encode_map_fn(text, label):
    """
    Required to convert the text to tensorflow data type.
    :param text and label
    :return: encoded text on tensorflow datatype.
    """
    encoded_text, label = tf.py_function(encode,
                                       inp=[text, label],
                                       Tout=(tf.int64, tf.int64))

    encoded_text.set_shape([None])
    label.set_shape([])

    return encoded_text, label

def labeler(example, index):
  return example, tf.cast(index, tf.int64)


def convert_request_to_model_input(request):
    """
    Given a request, returns a encoded value
    :param request: Input request
    :return: encoded value
    """
    notif = request['notificationLabel'].lower()
    notifCleaned = ' '.join([t if t in vocab_dict else 'UNK' for t in notif.split() ])
    lines_syntest = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(np.array([notifCleaned]))
    labeled_syntest = lines_syntest.map(lambda ex: labeler(ex, 0))

    all_encoded_syntest = labeled_syntest.map(encode_map_fn)
    syntest_data = all_encoded_syntest.padded_batch(7, padded_shapes=([None],[]))
    return syntest_data

start_load = time.time()
# Store the session so that we can execute the model prediction in the same session.
# This is needed in a multi-threaded environment
session = tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph())
with session.graph.as_default():
    tf.keras.backend.set_session(session)
    model_britney = tf.keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
print(f"Time for load- {time.time()-start_load}")

start = time.time()
    with session.graph.as_default():
        start_session = time.time()
        tf.compat.v1.keras.backend.set_session(session)
        print(f"Time for session setting - {time.time()-start_session}")
        start_predict = time.time()
        model_input = convert_request_to_model_input(request)
        proba_syntest_britney = model_britney.predict(model_input)
        print(f"Time for model prediction - {time.time()-start_predict}")

```
````

Comment: Seems like it could be due to a the model structure being changed. A new tensor could have been added, that was not in the previous model thst you're loading, so that it got shifted and added the wrong type and/or shape.

Comment: Try to print summary of the model just before variable start is declared.

print(model_britney.summary())